# adding a list of values as a column with sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

using sqlite3, lets say I have a table with 2000 rows. to it, I would like to add a new column. 
I have this column as a list of 2000 values (as an actual python list). how can I add this list as a column of the table?
I have seen the command ALTER_TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE {tableName} ADD COLUMN COLNew {type};
```

which seems like it allows me to provide a column name and a column data type, but where do I add the values of this column?

Also, I have seen the command:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name=new_value
```

but even here there seem to be only a way to enter a value based on a condition. it seems like it is not suitable to a case where I have the values ready.

Comment: Why is python tagged?

Comment: I use sqlite3, and I have the values as a python list

Comment: You need a way to figure out, for any given element of your list, which row should be updated with that value.

Comment: You don't insert values in columns that way in SQL. You alter the table to add the new column, and then you either UPDATE that column value for each existing row or you INSERT new rows that include the value for that column. You do this either for every row or for row that you select,. You always process the table row by row (each row will use only one of your column values list).

Comment: You could consider appending your column to the table in python (treating the list like an array, and the table like a dataframe). Might be a bit hacky, but possibly more legible and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

When using `ALTER TABLE ? ADD COLUMN ? ....`

The value in the new column will be null OR if you use DEFAULT the_default_value the column will be set to the defauly value.

You can then use and UPDATE to set the values, if the values can easily be derived from previously existing columns.

For example consider the following simple example :-

```
/* Create the original environment/data */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, myfirstcolumn TEXT);
INSERT INTO mytable (myfirstcolumn) VALUES 
        ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),
        ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F');

/* Display the data prior to adding the new column */
SELECT * FROM mytable;

/* Add the new column with default value of Z  and then display the table*/
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN mysecondcolumn TEXT DEFAULT 'Z'; /* sets all columns to z */
SELECT * FROM mytable;

/* Example of updating the data in the new column */
UPDATE mytable 
    SET mysecondcolumn = 
        CASE 
            WHEN myfirstcolumn = 'A' THEN 'ZA' /* IF myfirstcolumn is A then make mysecondcolumn ZA */
            WHEN myfirstcolumn = 'B' THEN 'YB' /* IF myfirstcolumn is B then make mysecondcolumn YB */
            WHEN myfirstcolumn = 'C' THEN 'XC' /* IF myfirstcolumn is C then make mysecondcolumn XC */
            ELSE 'ZZ'  /* IF myfirstcolumn is not A, B or C then make mysecondcolumn ZZ */
        END
    WHERE mysecondcolumn = 'Z' /* not really required as all rows will have Z */
;
/* Display end results */
SELECT * FROM mytable;
/* Clean up testing environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
```

## Results

### Initial Table

[image]

### Table after ALTER

[image]

### Table after UPDATE

[image]

## Example 2 - via a list

```
/* Create the original environment/data */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, myfirstcolumn TEXT);
INSERT INTO mytable (myfirstcolumn) VALUES 
        ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),
        ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F');

/* Display the data prior to adding the new column */
SELECT * FROM mytable;

/* Add the new column with default value of Z  and then display the table*/
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN mysecondcolumn TEXT DEFAULT 'Z'; /* sets all columns to z */
SELECT * FROM mytable;

/* Example of updating the data from a list containing first column value and value to use  */

/* A temporary table build from the list */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myvalueslist;
CREATE TEMP TABLE myvalueslist (lookupvalue TEXT PRIMARY KEY, replacevalue TEXT);
INSERT INTO myvalueslist VALUES ('A','ZA'),('B','YB'),('C','XC'),('F','UF'); 

/* Do the update */
UPDATE mytable 
    SET mysecondcolumn = coalesce((SELECT replacevalue FROM myvalueslist WHERE myfirstcolumn = lookupvalue),'ZZ')
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myvalueslist;
/* Display end results */
SELECT * FROM mytable;
/* Clean up testing environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
```

The results are similar, the only difference being that an additional condition has been added that the 2nd column will be UF when the first column is F (rather than the default ZZ) :-

[image]